# Cloudformation: Using Fn::Join and Fn:GetAtt together

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to define value in one of the attributes for `Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping` 
Below is my snippet (latest attempt):

```
FunctionName: #trigger the echo function previously defined
        "Fn::Join": [":", [{"Fn::GetAtt" : ["LambdaName", "Arn"]}, "live" ]]
```

My cloud formation stack, however fails to deploy with following error:

`"StatusReason": "Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined."`

I have tried couple of variations with the brackets, however keep getting same error. What am I missing in the syntax?

P.S. I am defining this in a yaml file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first question is whether LambdaName references something that can be used with GetAtt to provide an ARN. Otherwise, it could just be a formatting issue. I'm not sure AWS CFN can read the embedded curly brackets you're using to wrap the `Fn::GetAtt`.

Maybe one of these would work better?

```
FunctionName:
  Fn::Join:
    - ':'
    - - Fn::GetAtt:
          - LambdaName
          - Arn
      - "live"
```

Or

```
FunctionName: !Join [':', [!GetAtt LambdaName.Arn, 'live]]
```

Comment: `LambdaName` was just a placeholder. It actually does reference a  lambda. I do believe I had tried this the second alternate and it hadn't worked for me earlier.  Anyways, using the second alternate using your syntax worked. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

```
LambdaSourceMapping:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
  Properties:
    Enabled: 'true'
    EventSourceArn: <SQS ARN> or <Kinesis ARN> or <DynamoDb ARN>
    FunctionName:
      Fn::Join:
      - ':'
      - - Fn::GetAtt:
          - LambdaName
          - Arn
        - 'live'
```